# Recursive globing using wildcard without adding extra directory level

Tags: python, recursion, glob

I am trying to construct absolute file paths with glob using wildcards. Using this code.

```
list_of_files = glob.glob(globable_file_path, recursive=True)
```

Now I feed this a list of globable file paths. When formatted like this it works

```
\?\Z:\level_1\level_2\**\*12345*.pdf
```

But the above is adding an extra level (\) of directory and I can not change the parent path. So I have been trying things like this

```
\?\Z:\level_1\level_2\**12345*.pdf
\?\Z:\level_1\level_2\[**]12345*.pdf
\?\Z:\level_1\level_2\**[12345]*.pdf
```

But none of these work. How would I be able to avoid adding an extra level of directory but glob recursively using wildcards?

The docs show this

```
>>> glob.glob('**/*.txt', recursive=True)
['2.txt', 'sub/3.txt']
>>> glob.glob('./**/', recursive=True)
['./', './sub/']
```

Which suggest you need the extra \ for recursive searching. Is there a way to do it with pathlib or os.path or some trick I do not know about?

Answer (score 0):

So this works using pathlib

```
from pathlib import Path

for path in Path(globable_file_path).rglob("*" + str(log1) + "*.pdf"):
    list_of_files.append(path.__str__())
```

I used the `__str__` method to convert from `WindowsPath` to string.